# How to create a new content in Google Sites by sending a POST request using Android or Curl?

Tags: android, http, post, curl, http-headers

Currently, I am working on creating a Android app to read and create google sites content. It seems like the java api doesn't work for Android, so I use google protocol 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ContentFeedPOST.
I can get all the content on google site by this GET request
https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/domainName.
But I have no idea how to send a POST request to create a content beside on the google api guide. 
Hope anyone could help me with this. All I need is how to send the request in curl.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try curl command like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: your-content-type" -X POST -d 'your-data' https://localhost:8080/api/login
```

And to post data using HttpUrlConnection class use following:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    try {
      //Create connection
      url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
           "your-content-type");//set required content type

      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
               data.getBytes().length);//set Content-Length header using your data length in bytes
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  


      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      //Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  connection.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (data);//write data to o/p stream
      wr.flush ();
      wr.close ();

      //Get Response    
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
      if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect(); 
      }
    }
```